# Can someone explain why this program behaves like this?

Tags: c

I have the following program in C:

```
void main() {
    int x[3];
    int* p = &x;
    printf("%d %d \n", p, x);
}
```

those values for `p` and `x` seem to be the same, but i dont understand why, since p is the address of pointer x, shouldn't there be something like `*p = x` instead of `p = x` ?

Comment: For starters, `int* p = &x;` shouldn't compile. If it compiles for you, you should probably switch to more strict compiler settings.

Comment: This isn't how you print the value of pointers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unfortunately C has rather weak type-checking, so it will probably compile but a warning should be issued as the types mismatch.

Comment: why is ```int *p = &x``` wrong ? is it supposed to be ```int **p``` ?

Comment: In this case, `x` and `&x` have the same value but different types.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Both GCC and Clang reject it with `-pedantic-errors`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Also, to print a pointer (really a `void *`) you should use the `printf` format `%p`. And you should really cast the pointer to the correct `void *` type.

Comment: @Verthais Nope. `x` is not a pointer. It is an array.

Comment: `&x` has type `int (*)[3]`, not `int*`. Also, you don't print p with `%d`.

Comment: `printf("%d %d \n", p, x);` --> `printf("%p %p \n", (void*)p, (void*)x);`

Answer (score 4):

The big problem is that `p` and `&x` are different types.

The pointer given by `&x` is a pointer to the whole array `x`, not to a single element, and its type is `int (*)[3]`, not `int *`.

If you want to get a pointer to the first element of `x` then use `&x[0]`, or plain `x` (as that decays to `&x[0]`).

And even while the types of `&x` and `&x[0]` are different, they both point to the same location (as your (invalid) printouts indicates). This can be seen if you attempt to visualize the array `x` in memory:

```
+------+------+------+
| x[0] | x[1] | x[2] |
+------+------+------+
^
|
&x
|
&x[0]
```

---

As I already mentioned in a comment, to print pointers you need to use the `%p` format specifier. Mismatching formatting specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

What's more, the `%p` format specifier is for `void *` pointers, so you need to cast the pointers (unless they are already `void *` of course):

```
printf("%p %p \n", (void *) p, (void *) x);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code produce some **warning** at compilation time :

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=] 
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
```

and your compiled code cause an **undefined behaviour** and the equal result is due to the Undefined behaviour.

***Tips***:
Your code is wrong conceptually, please read more on pointer, array e type in C language.

Comment: Technically, `int* p = &x;` makes the code ill-formed rather than causing UB (it shouldn't compile). If we ignore that, `printf("%d %d \n", p, x);` does cause UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `int* p = &x;` falls under "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting
pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.", so potential UB.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your program leading to undefined behaviour.

First, array `x` is not initialized, and accessing it later leads to UB.

Second, `x` when used as pointer is already the address of the first element of array `x` (equivalent to `&x[0]`); Hence `&x` would be a pointer to that pointer.
Third, `%d` requires an integral value, not a pointer to one; so you need to dereference `p` and `x`.

The following program should behave as you expect:

```
int main() {
    int x[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    int* p = x;
    printf("%d %d \n", *p, x[0]);
}
```

Comment: " accessing it later leads to UB." --> OP's code does not access the contents of `x`, just its address, so no UB on that.

Comment: "Hence `&x` would be a pointer to that pointer." --> `&x` is a pointer to an array.  An array is not a pointer, a pointer is not an array.  `&x` is type `int (*)[3]`.